# What does the dot do in Racket?

Tags: syntax, racket

I know the dot for creating a procedure, which can take an arbitrary amount of arguments, but I saw several other examples, which use the dot in other places. One example is from the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/csv-reading/) of `csv-reading`:

> ```
> (define next-row
>   (make-csv-reader
>    (open-input-file "fruits.csv")
>    '((separator-chars            #\|)
>      (strip-leading-whitespace?  . #t)
>      (strip-trailing-whitespace? . #t))))
> ```

To me this looks like a list of configuration parameters is "set", but what does the dot do there?

Another example is from a web application tutorial from the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/) (in the formlet section) as well:

> ```
> ; new-post-formlet : formlet (values string? string?)
> ; A formlet for requesting a title and body of a post
> (define new-post-formlet
>   (formlet
>    (#%# ,{input-string . => . title}
>         ,{input-string . => . body})
>    (values title body)))
> ```

My guess for this example is, that the dots somehow allow to write `=>` as an infix operator. I was able to put the `=>` at the front of the lists and leave the dots away and it still worked at some point. I didn't try with the final version of the tutorial's code though.
However, this "infixing" wouldn't fit the first example, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dot` is not uniquely a racket thing, but a lisp thing. A list is made out of pairs and one pair has the literal form `(car . cdr)` and a list of the elements `2, 3` is made up like `(2 . (3 . ()))` and the reader can read this, however a list that has a pair as it's `cdr` can be shown without the dot and the parens such that `(2 . (3 . ()))` is the same as `(2 3 . ())`. Also a dot with the special empty list in the end can be omitted so that `(2 3)` is how it can be read and the only way `display` and the REPL would print it.

What happens if you don't have a pair or null as the `cdr`? Then the only way to represent it is as a dotted. With `(2 . (3 . 5))` you can only simplify the first dot so it's `(2 3 . 5)`.

The literal data structure looks like an `assoc` with pairs as elements where the `car` is the key and `cdr` is the value. Using a new pair is just wast of space.

As an parameter list an interpreter looks at the elements and if it's a pair it binds the symbol in `car`, but if it's not a pair it is either finished with null or you have a rest argument symbol. It's convenient way to express it. Clojure that don't have dotted pairs use a `&` element while Common Lisp does dotted in structures, but not as a parameter specification since it supports more features than Scheme and Clojure and thus use special keywords to express it instead.

The second is `#lang racket` specific and is indeed used to support infix. If you write `(5 . + . 6)` a reader extension will change it to `(+ 5 6)` before it gets evaluated. It works the same way even if it's quoted or actual code and curlies are of course equal to normal and square parentheses so the second one actually becomes:

```
(define new-post-formlet
  (formlet
   (#%# ,(=> input-string title)
        ,(=> input-string body))
   (values title body)))
```

If you were to use `#!r5rs` or `#!r6rs` in racket `(5 . + . 6)` will give you a read error.

Comment: A new pair in this case is wasteful, because I do not need any new memory when writing the association with `(something . somethingelse)`, because I only specify arguments and don't build any new structure. However, when I create a pair, I'd force the allocation of memory for that pair. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Zelphir Almost `(something . somethingelse)` uses only one pair while the alternative `(something somethingelse)` uses two. Twice the space and twice the path to get to `somethingelse`, however nowdays this doesn't matter as much as it did back then we had only kilobytes available so today it's more of a habit and of course the one who has implemented `cvs-reader` did it out of habit rather than need.